# Why Composite Primary Key is not added as a Foreign Key in psql (rails app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, foreign-keys, psql, composite-primary-key

I am using `activerecord-multi-tenant` gem for implementing MultiTenancy in my rails project.

Followed instruction from [here](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v7.2/migration/transitioning.html)

I have a `User` model, `Attendance` Model which belongs to `User`, And `Company` as a tenant.

While I am updating User's `primary key(id)` to `composite key(id, company_id)` It is updating.

But when I am trying to update the Foreign key in  `Attendance` models it is only trying to take `user_id` as a fk and searching for its unique constraint.

Here is the commands i used -

```
execute 'ALTER TABLE users DROP CONSTRAINT users_pkey;'
execute 'ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id, company_id);'

execute 'ALTER TABLE attendances DROP CONSTRAINT attendances_pkey;'
execute 'ALTER TABLE attendances ADD CONSTRAINT attendances_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, company_id);'
execute 'ALTER TABLE attendances ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id, company_id) REFERENCES users(id, company_id);'
```

The Error i am getting while `schema:load`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidForeignKey: ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"
: ALTER TABLE "attendances" ADD CONSTRAINT "attendances_user_id_company_id_fkey"
FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
  REFERENCES "users" ("id")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using `structure.sql` file.
In `schema.rb` file it cant always follow the sql command and reflect in the database. So I was getting this error `InvalidForeignKey` as schema couldn't load the sql command properly.

After moving to `structure.sql` all the migration were run properly with exact commands inside the files.